# Ошибка при вставке изображений в кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, visual-studio-2012

После добавления картинки в кнопку стала вылезать такая ошибка:
[image: Сама ошибка]

На 7 строке (и вокруг)

```
public MainPlatform()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Как чинить?

---

Кнопка и ее свойства:

```
<Window x:Class="-----_alpha_wpf.MainPlatform"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Background="White" Height="720" Width="1280" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" MinWidth="1280" MinHeight="720" Title="----">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,604,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="76" Foreground="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF006600">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/main_icon_alpha.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите ваш XAML код кнопки с картинкой

Comment: @Bulson Добавил

Comment: А почему не как `Content` добавляете?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515631/add-an-image-in-a-wpf-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинка не была ресурсом, поэтому не вставлялась.
Чтобы сделать её ресурсом нужно открыть "Свойства" картинки, и в поле "Действие сборки" выбрать Resource.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]