# Как переписать стиль для кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, visual-studio-2012

Как можно переписать стиль кнопки чтобы при наведении мыши не было градиента от Windows и после нажатия кнопка не мигала (тем же градиентом)?

Comment: Покажите код, как вы пытались это сделать.

Comment: @kxxko Никак не пытался, т.к даже не знаю как это пишется.

Comment: [Открывайте MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx), копируйте стиль оттуда и правьте как вам надо. Я рекомендую вам установить последнюю версию студии (2017), там есть возможность получить стиль элемента не копаясь в MSDN.

Comment: ЗЫ: если вы пишете этот вопрос как следствие [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718712/Ошибка-при-вставке-изображений-в-кнопку) и у вас исчезает картинка при наведении курсора мыши - установите эту картинку в качестве контента, а не кисти фона.

Comment: [Еще статья на MSDN по теме](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Андрей Нет, картинка уже не исчезает. Спасибо.